# What design-pattern I should use in my notification system?

Tags: email, design-patterns, push-notification, notifications

Which design-pattern I should use in this case:

I have a rest API notification system.

I can notify by Email

notify by push;

notify by WhatsApp.

And I want to implement more technologies, and I do not want to modify the core, I want to add only modules to the system. For example, adding Telegram Messages, Twitter messages, or another email provider.

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your problem statement, two different types of design patterns will be involved:

1) **Strategy Pattern**: It will define the notification strategy based on the contexts like email, push, whatsapp, etc.

3) **Observer Pattern**: It will perform the publisher and subscribers operation will the behavior of loose coupling. It will automatically notify to subcriber.

You can also integrate **RabbitMq** somewhere for queuing and on time pushing messages.

Comment: I do, RabbitMQ and NServiceBus

Answer (score 3):

The case you explained is like strategy design pattern . You can use strategy design pattern and have an interface and a class for your each system that implement your interface. These are links that can help you :

[tutsplus design ptterns](https://code.tutsplus.com/series/design-patterns-in-php--cms-747)

[designpatternsphp](https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 3):

For a notification system I would suggest you using the Observer pattern. The message you receive should be inside your `Subject`. Subject should allow any number of `Observers` to attach. When a message is received, the subject should notify all the observers. Then `Observers` can read the state/message from the subject and act upon it. I am not pretty much clear about your usecase. But this would do the job.

Answer (score 2):

observer - observable pattern suits for you. if u use any frameworks ( spring in java) built in futures - like event listener & publisher - this really reduces ur burden of implementations.

i hope u r already using frameworks - so research on event listener + publisher. it really solves ur problem ..not only enhancing support to multiple vendors.. it also supports - single - multi thread with less changes.

Answer (score 1):

To me seems a PUB-SUB model or a Observer pattern is best, extension in the form of subscriber registered to publisher works well as subscriber can have their own implementation details abstracting away from core notification service.

Comment: maybe in a more complex scenario it could be good to use observer pattern (probably combining it with strategy), but in this case, with these informations, i think it's not useful

Answer (score 1):

Strategy Pattern:

Define a family of algorithms (your types of notifications), encapsulate each one (each type of notification), and make them interchangeable (with a common abstraction). **Strategy lets the algorithm vary independently from the clients that use it**.
Capture the abstraction in an interface, bury implementation details in derived classes.

Each time you want to add different types of notification you will add new strategies (Twitter, Telegram, ecc)